# Integrate the partial differential equation $v_{yyy} + v \cdot v_y + c \cdot v_y = 0$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I am finding group invariant solutions for a partial differential equation.  The equation I am working with is
$$
u_t - uu_x - u_{xxx} = 0
$$

From the symmetries I have the following characteristic equation to solve in order to find travelling wave solutions.
$$
\frac{dx}{c} = \frac{dt}{1}
$$

I introduce variables $v = h(y)$ and $y$.

in solving the above equation I have
\begin{align}
y &= x - ct \\
v & = u\\
\end{align}

So I have $u = h(x-ct)$

\begin{align}
u_x & = v_y \\
u_{xxx} & = v_{yyy}\\
u_t & = -cv_y\\
\end{align}

Now when I substitute this into the given PDE I get:

$$
-cv_y - v \cdot v_y - v_{yyy} = 0 \\
v_{yyy} + v \cdot v_y + c \cdot v_y = 0
$$

The solution has :
$$
v_{yy} + \frac{1}{2}v^2 +cv = k
$$

I want to confirm how the second term is found.

Using integration by parts: let $a = \int v \cdot v_y dy$

I then get:
$$
a = v^2 - a \\
2a = v^2 \\
a = \frac{1}{2}v^2\\
$$

Comment: Chain rule: $(v^2)_y = v\cdot v_y+v_y\cdot v = 2v\cdot v_y$